# How use non-static value in annotation FindsBy?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, annotations, pageobjects

I was trying to convert the whole definition of my locators from standart format to annotation FindsBy using POM. But I have some locators, which consist of non-static variables and I`m getting error message: "Cannot access non-static field _createBookData in static context".

Code, which I want to get:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using ="#select-month > option:nth-child(" + _createBookData.NumberMonth + ")")  ]  private IWebElement BirthmonthDropItem;
```

Instead of this code:

```
 private IWebElement BirthmonthDropItem
    {            
        get
        {
            return _waitDriver.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("#select-month > option:nth-child(" + _createBookData.NumberMonth + ")")));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do this. Attributes are and must be entirely defined at compile time, not at runtime. This is just the way the C# language works. It is by design; there is no workaround to do this with attributes. Luckily, the Page Object Model has no dependency on using the `PageFactory` implementation. Using `PageFactory` provides no discernible benefit over other methods of populating a Page Object.